# Flash IDE text mask reverses

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gradient, mask

I am trying to make a gradient mask over my text. It looks great the gradient fills the shape of my text. When I publish the flash video the text and gradient switch. The text is no longer  masked and I cannot seem to figure out why. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

The top half is what it looks like inside the IDE, the bottom half is when it's published.

[image: The top half is what it looks like inside the IDE, the bottom half is when it's published.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the gradient as your object, and the text as the mask. You might have to convert the text to a vector shape instead to do this. Not sure why in the IDE it looks right and published it doesn't, but a gradient mask is not what you want if understand the question correctly.

To clarify, did you have a gray (black to white) gradient, or not? Example files or screen shots would help if you still can't figure it out.

Further, are you using any code to do this, to make a dynamic animation perhaps? If not, you can just fill your text with the desired gradient instead of having one mask the other.

Comment: +1 I placed the Dynamic textbox inside a movieclip and it worked. Thanks